# Execute a script with SQLPlus containing html entity mappings

Tags: sqlplus

When executing a script with SQL PLus, I was prompted to enter value for lt, gt, and apos.

Here are some code examples in this script.

```
v_qry := replace(v_qry, '&lt;', '<');
v_qry := replace(v_qry, '&gt;', '>');
v_qry := replace(v_qry, '&apos;', '''') ;
```

How to execute this script without being prompted to enter values?

Thank you
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set define off
```

More details can be found in the manual: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2698854